# Read a variable dynamically set in thread from a different thread

Tags: python, multithreading

Probably the wrong way to think about doing this, but I am trying to dynamically set a variable in one thread then occasionally read the variable in another thread.  In the first thread I am going to be checking the status of something every 30 seconds and setting a variable to indicate whether it's up or down.  In the second thread I am going to be listening to a socket, and when something comes into the socket I need to read the variable from the first thread to determine the up/down status.

Comment: If your two threads are both classes, simply pass a shared object (list, queue, etc) or the instance of the first thread, to the second thread.  ex: t1 = ClassA(); t2 = ClassB(t1); t1.run(); t2.run(); ClassB asks, self.t1.isvarset();

Comment: fairly nice example: http://softwareramblings.com/2008/06/running-functions-as-threads-in-python.html